# Encoding issues while saving json to file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I am reading logs from mobile device, from system terminal line by line and saving it to string.

Then I cut this string into parts and want to generate .*json file from it.

I have my .*json in form of dictionary and I want to save it to file with usage of this custom made method:

```
def save_json_to_file(json_dict, folder, file_name, extension):
    directory = add_ending_slash(GlobalConfig.OUTPUT_DIR) + add_ending_slash(str(folder))
    file_path = clean_path(directory + str(file_name) + "." + extension)

    output_file = None
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        output_file = open(file_path, "w")
        absolute_path = os.path.abspath(file_path)

        Printer.system_message(TAG, "Created json file '" + absolute_path + "'.")

        json.dump(json_dict, output_file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    except Exception as e:
        message = "Unable to create file '{}.{}'. Error message: {}"
        message = message.format(file_path, extension, str(e))
        raise LauncherFlowInterruptedException(TAG, message)
    finally:
        if output_file is not None and hasattr(output_file, "close"):
            output_file.close()

    return absolute_path
```

At some point of `json.dump` doing it's job I get crash:

```
  File "/Users/F1sherKK/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 89: invalid start byte
```

I tried changing every string I receive from console by doing:

```
received_terminal_line = received_terminal_line.encode('utf-8')
```

I know that in incoming strings there can be various different encodings, in example emoji.

Comment: Try `received_terminal_line.decode('latin1')`. This may help because arbitrary binary strings are valid latin1 which can always be decoded to Unicode and then encoded back to the original string again (with a `.encode('latin1')`).

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode', should I encode it with 'utf-8' and decode with 'latin1'?

Comment: You must be using Python 3. Try `bytes(received_terminal_line).decode('latin1')`.

Comment: I have python3, `bytes(received_terminal_line).decode('latin1')` returns this error `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`

Comment: `bytes(received_terminal_line, 'latin1').decode('latin1')` should workaround that.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help :(  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 89: invalid start byte` is still there

Comment: If you would provide something runnable (see [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), you'll be much more likely to get a full-blown answer.